# Permission denied while trying to use supervisor on docker container

Tags: docker, supervisord

I am trying to run a container using `x11docker`, I am trying to execute a startup script after the container is start to run without freezing the whole process.

my OS is Ubuntu LTS 22.04

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM x11docker/xfce

WORKDIR /data

RUN apt-get update & apt-get install -y \ python3 \ python-pip3 \ supervisor

COPY startup.sh /usr/local/bin/startup.sh
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/startup.sh
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]
```

After running the docker build and running the image I am getting this error:

> permissionError: [errno 13] Permission denied:
> '/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log'

I will appreciate your help!

Comment: Have same issue, running as root

Comment: I think. I used the docker image with erased /tmp folder. Because of it the /tmp folder was created again with some bad permissions, so even root user could not put files there

Answer (score -1):

While docker should be running as the root user by default, is it possible your docker container us running as a non-root user?

Try and re-run your container with `sudo` appended at the beginning to ensure your running as root:

`sudo docker run hello-world`

More details running docker as non-root users:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user